# min of an arrayList without considering zero

Tags: java, arraylist, min

I have an arrayList such as [2.3, 0.0, 1.34, 0.0, 4.3] and I want to find the minimum value of this arrayList but without considering zero in this array. It means I am looking for a function that returns 1.34 as minimum among 2.3, 1.3 and 4.3 in the mentioned list. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show us your efforts. This looks very straight to work.

Comment: Please post the two lines of code you have already written that solve your problem, but that you (for an uspecified reason) are still not happy with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. Write a for loop that iterates over the array, set an double variable equal to the smallest value from your array. Unless the value is zero, then ignore it. What part are you having trouble with?